# unity android deep linking not working

Tags: android, deep-linking

Im developing a mobile app using unity and I want to deep link the mobile app to the website. I have edited the androidmanifest as shown in the developers site but even though the building process runs smoothly when i try to type the link on the browser and launch the app it does not work

```
<activity android:name="com.liveroom.liveroom.GalleryUpdater"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
               <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
             <data android:scheme="liveroom"
               android:host="liveview"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
        </activity>
```

as stated in the [developers article](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) the intent should be able to access and load the app when the uri liveroom://liveview but itt does not do so. please point my mistake, thank you

Comment: when you type on browser it will not open . to test make an html file using <a href then it will open

Comment: Done thank you for the support

Comment: its done using my approach ?

Comment: yes I added the href to a text and it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type on browser it will not open . to test make an html file using < a href tag then it will open.

Answer (score 0):

Not every browser supports deep linking, only few browser supports deep linking, like if you want to check deep linking, use google chrome latest updated browser , so when You test deep linking using QR code it will open perticular app.

Answer (score 0):

Was also not working for me. What helped was to remove `android:host="(...)"`

So my AndroidManifest.xml now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <application>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="unitydl" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```